# CHECK constraint in SQL Server, via GUI or manually?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2012

I want to add a check constraint to an already-existing table which does a check based upon a SELECT COUNT(*) statement. I know my SELECT statement but when I have created the DROP AND CREATE TO script I am unsure where to add my code and what format it should take?

Is there a way to do this in the GUI, or could someone show me an example of a CREATE table statement with a CHECK constraint, considering of a SELECT COUNT(*)?

I know that a CHECK constraint just has to evaluate to a boolean from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There is an example of adding a `CHECK` constraint to a table in the documentation that you linked to, can you be more specific about what you don't understand? And the same page links to [Creating and Modifying CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx) which has more information and examples. I suspect your real difficulty is using `COUNT()`, but you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve so it's difficult to say what the best response is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing of note is that you cannot directly use sub-queries in check constraints, but creating a function is the way around that.  This will help you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRedRows()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Return INT
    SELECT @Return=COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Red
    RETURN @Return
END
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Red 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    test VARCHAR(max), 
    CONSTRAINT CK_MaxRows CHECK (dbo.fnRedRows()<5)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Red (test) VALUES ('HI')
INSERT INTO dbo.Red (test) VALUES ('The')
INSERT INTO dbo.Red (test) VALUES ('first four')
INSERT INTO dbo.Red (test) VALUES ('will work')
INSERT INTO dbo.Red (test) VALUES ('This one will fail')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Red
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnRedRows
GO
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to replicate a table-based assertion. However, I understand SQL Server cannot do assertions? Am I right in using a check constraint for this? My constraint is to enforce row count.